# Large files with local git repo

Tags: ssh, git

I have a computer running ubuntu, which I use as a git server. I have a bunch of other computers connected to the same network which regularly push and pull from the git repo on my local git server. This git repo is only used locally by computers on the same network. Nothing goes to the outside internet.

I want to be able to handle large files, and have those large files saved on a local folder on the computer that I am using as the git server. I tried setting up git lfs, but it seems like that only allows you to point to an http or https location. I want it to be in a local folder.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this task (dealing with large files in the git repo), while keeping my git repo on a local computer functioning as my git repo. I am fine doing this either with lfs or some other way.

I know one option is to set up an lfs test server but I do not want the information to be going through the outside internet. I just want to keep everything local.